Error during transcription with Deepgram API: 401 Unauthorized when sending audio from Twilio
I'm trying to transcribe an audio file from Twilio using Deepgram API, but I’m encountering a 401 Unauthorized error when attempting to transcribe the audio.
Here’s my code:
async def transcribe_audio(audio_url: str) -> dict:
    try:
        print(f"Sending audio to Deepgram for transcription: {audio_url}")
        response = requests.get(audio_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN))

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Successfully fetched the audio file from Twilio.")
            
            options = PrerecordedOptions(
                model="nova-2",
                smart_format=True,
                language="en",
                punctuate=True
            )

            response = await deepgram_client.listen.rest.v("1").transcribe_url(
                {"url": audio_url}, 
                options
            )

            print(f"Deepgram Response: {response}")

            if response and hasattr(response, 'results'):
                transcript = response.results.channels[0].alternatives[0].transcript
                return {
                    "transcription": transcript,
                    "confidence": response.results.channels[0].alternatives[0].confidence
                }
            else:
                raise ValueError("No transcription results found in the response")

        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Failed to fetch audio from Twilio. HTTP Status Code: {response.status_code}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during transcription: {e}")
        return {"error": str(e)}

Here’s what happens:

I’m successfully fetching the audio file from Twilio using the requests.get method.
Then, I send the audio URL to Deepgram for transcription via the deepgram_client.listen.rest.v("1").transcribe_url method.
The API call fails with a 401 Unauthorized error, even though the Twilio authentication (HTTPBasicAuth(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)) is correct.

The error message I’m getting is:
Error during transcription: DeepgramApiError: The remote server hosting the media returned a client error: 401 Unauthorized. (Status: 400)

My environment:

Twilio API: Used to fetch audio from Twilio.
Deepgram API: Used to transcribe the audio file.

I have tried checking my API keys, and they seem fine, but I’m still facing this issue.

